# React Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context of ApolloConsumer. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have a React app using `react-apollo:2.5.8` and a library of custom components that I install via NPM and use within the app. The library has `react-apollo:2.5.8` listed in peer and dev dependencies. Ever since I upgraded react-apollo to 2.5.8 I have been getting this error

```
`Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context of ApolloConsumer. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider>.`
```

I tried listing React-apollo within `externals` in the Webpack build for the library as well. This way only one installation is used, within the App. But no luck. Every time I try to import the components I keep getting this error. The components within the app are able to query successfully, it's the library components that throw this error.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this? I don't want to upgrade to ^3.0.0 as there are breaking changes and would involve a lot of refactoring. I am server side rendering the app as well, in which case it works perfectly fine, and I don't get this error. It's when I try to run the client only version that this error crops up.

Update: I can see that the library components still seem to be using their own react-apollo from it's node_modules folder. The module format is `ejs`, whereas in the app, the module format is the main option `cjs`. This is probably causing the error. I'll see if I can prevent the library components from using their own `react-apollo` package.

Comment: Are you importing the Provider and your hooks/Components from the same package? i.e. only `react-apollo` and not `react-apollo` and `@apollo/react-hooks`?

Comment: Yes, only `react-apollo`. Since I'm still at `2.5.8` I'm not using Hooks

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by creating a symlink to the `react-apollo` package within my App from my library components folder. Since this was mainly a requirement for the dev environment, this seems to fix the problem. Not the best solution, but works for now.